# Fail2Ban not blocking failed postfix login under plesk

Tags: iptables, plesk, fail2ban

I have plesk 12.0.18 Update #96
OS: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
i have installed fail2ban through plesk and for some reason it's not blocking failed attempt on postfix server.

```
Dec 20 08:34:53 website postfix/smtpd[6696]: warning: unknown[37.216.243.35]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Dec 20 08:34:56 website postfix/smtpd[27244]: warning: unknown[37.216.243.35]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Dec 20 08:35:00 website postfix/smtpd[7415]: warning: unknown[37.216.243.35]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Dec 20 08:35:32 website postfix/smtpd[6582]: warning: unknown[37.216.243.35]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Dec 20 08:35:35 website postfix/smtpd[29514]: warning: unknown[37.216.243.35]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Dec 20 08:35:41 website postfix/smtpd[6582]: warning: unknown[37.216.243.35]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Dec 20 08:36:03 website postfix/smtpd[6582]: warning: unknown[37.216.243.35]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Dec 20 08:36:06 website postfix/smtpd[6696]: warning: unknown[37.216.243.35]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Dec 20 08:36:09 website postfix/smtpd[27244]: warning: unknown[37.216.243.35]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Dec 20 08:36:15 website postfix/smtpd[6696]: warning: unknown[37.216.243.35]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Dec 20 08:36:21 website postfix/smtpd[6696]: warning: unknown[37.216.243.35]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Dec 20 08:36:24 website postfix/smtpd[27244]: warning: unknown[37.216.243.35]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Dec 20 08:36:27 website postfix/smtpd[6696]: warning: unknown[37.216.243.35]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
```

i had to block this ip myslef through iptables -I when i'm checking the logs of fail2ban there is nothing there that even show an attempt to block the ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it. there was a problem with the filter that didnt match it + the rule for ip table was wrong for some reason. and that was the default installation.